# How to get temperature units on weather api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am working on Reactjs weather project, which gets data from particular weather api. On loading of project, I get temperature info of my city which tracks via getCurrentPosition function. The temperature unit could also changed via toggle switch from celcius to farenheit and vice-versa which was my main target. But, how to get temperature units value on particular city search?. In short,I want to toggle switch temperature unit on city search.

Following are the files for reference
1. App.js (Main File)

```
class App extends React.Component  { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      lat: '',
      lon: '',
      city: '',
      country: '',
      humidity: '',
      temperature: '',
      wind: '',
      description: '',
      maxTemp: '',
      minTemp: '',
      precip: '',
      pressure: '',
      hourlyforecast: '',
      error: '',
      unit: 'C',
      sunrise: '',
      sunset: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {

      // Tracking the location and 
      // Setting the state of latitude and longitude values
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
        this.setState({
          lat:  position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3),
          lon: position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3)
        }, () => { 
           if(this.state.lat && this.state.lon) {
            this.fetchWeather()
          } else {
            this.getWeather()
          }
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(`${error.message}`,{
          autoClose: 3000
        })
    },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })
  }


fetchWeather = () => {
  const {lat, lon} = this.state
  const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'C') ? 'M' : 'I';
  console.log('UNITTYPE', unitType)

        // Current Weather
  fetch(`${CURRENT_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      console.log('DATA CURRENT', responseJson)
    this.setState({
    city: responseJson.data[0].city_name,
    country: responseJson.data[0].country_code,
    temperature: responseJson.data[0].temp,
    wind: responseJson.data[0].wind_spd,
    humidity: responseJson.data[0].rh,
    pressure: responseJson.data[0].pres,
    description: responseJson.data[0].weather.description,
    isLoading: false, 
    }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    })
    } catch {
      toast.error('Error Code 429')
    }

  });

  // Forecast Weather - Daily
  fetch(`${FORECAST_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&days=6&key=${API_KEY3}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      console.log('DATA I GET', responseJson)
      this.setState({
      forecastdays: responseJson.data,
      precip: responseJson.data[0].pop,
      maxTemp: responseJson.data[0].app_max_temp,
      sunrise: responseJson.data[0].sunrise_ts,
      sunset: responseJson.data[0].sunset_ts,
      minTemp: responseJson.data[0].app_min_temp,
      isLoading: false 
      } , () => {
        localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })
    } catch {
      toast.error('Too many requests')
    }

  });


  // Forecast Weather - Hourly
  fetch(`${HOURLY_API}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}&hours=10`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    try {
      this.setState({
        hourlyforecast: responseJson.data,
        isLoading: false
      }, () => {
        localStorage.setItem('weather', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })

    } catch {
      toast.error('Please wait some time')
    }

  });
  }
```

2. Function that outputs toggle switch values

```
onUnitChange = (newUnit) => {
    this.setState({
        unit: newUnit
    }, this.fetchWeather, this.getWeather)
}
```

Till above code I get the output

Now the question comes -> How to pass the unit value to getWeather function?

3. Function that searches weather info based on city input

```
  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const unitType = (this.state.unit === 'C') ? 'M' : 'I';

    try {
      // 1. weatherbit current data
      const api_call4 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?` + 
      `city=${city}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}`)
      const data4 = await api_call4.json();
      console.log('DATA CURRENT', data4)

      // 2. weatherbit forecast data
      const api_call3 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily` + 
      `?city=${city}&units=${unitType}&days=6&key=${API_KEY3}`)
      const data3 = await api_call3.json();
      console.log('DATA FORECAST', data3)

      // 3. weatherbit hourly data
      const api_call2 = await fetch(`https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/hourly` + 
      `?city=${city}&units=${unitType}&key=${API_KEY3}&hours=10`)
      const data2 = await api_call2.json();
      console.log('DATA HOURLY', data2)

      if(city) {
      this.setState({
        temperature: data4.data[0].temp,
        city: data4.data[0].city_name,
        country: data4.data[0].country_code,
        humidity: data4.data[0].rh,
        maxTemp: data4.data[0].app_max_temp,
        minTemp: data4.data[0].app_min_temp,
        wind: data4.data[0].wind_spd,
        description: data4.data[0].weather.description,
        pressure: data4.data[0].pres,
        error: "",
        precip: data3.data[0].pop,
        forecastdays: data3.data,
        hourlyforecast: data2.data,        
        maxTemp: data3.data[0].app_max_temp,
        minTemp: data3.data[0].app_min_temp,
        sunrise: data3.data[0].sunrise_ts,
        sunset: data3.data[0].sunset_ts,
        isLoading: false
      }, () => {
        localStorage.setItem('weather2', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      })
    } else if(city === '') {
      this.setState({
        temperature: this.state.temperature,
        city: this.state.city,
        country: this.state.country,
        humidity: this.state.humidity,
        wind: this.state.wind,
        description: this.state.description,
        pressure: this.state.pressure,
        forecastdays: this.state.forecastdays,
        hourlyforecast: this.state.hourlyforecast,
        precip: this.state.precip,
        maxTemp: this.state.maxTemp,
        minTemp: this.state.minTemp,
        error: toast.error("City cannot be empty",{
          autoClose: 3000
        })
      })

    } 
    }

    catch {
      toast.error('No Data Received', {
        autoClose: 3000
      })
    }

    localStorage.getItem('weather2')
  }

render() {
    const {isLoading, forecastdays, hourlyforecast, precip} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container" style={{marginTop: '3.5em'}}>
        <div className="row">

            <div className="col-sm-4 form-container">
              <Form getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
              <ToastContainer transition={Bounce} 
              className = 'toast-background'/>    
            </div>  

          {isLoading ? <Spinner/>:  

          <React.Fragment>
          <div className="col-sm-8 image-container">
          {/* Weather Card */}
          <div className="background">
          <div className="container"> 
          <div id="card" className="weather" style={sectionStyle}></div>    
          <div id="card" className="weather2" style={{background: ''}}>

                  <div className="details">
                      {/* Weather Details */}
                       <div className="content" style={{width: '125px'}}>
                        <Weather
                          temperature={this.state.temperature}
                          city={this.state.city}
                          country={this.state.country}
                          humidity={this.state.humidity}
                          description={this.state.description}
                          pressure={this.state.pressure}
                          wind={this.state.wind}
                          maxTemp={this.state.maxTemp}
                          minTemp={this.state.minTemp}
                          precip={precip}
                          tempUnit={this.state.tempUnit}
                          />

                       </div>

                      {/* Forecast Cards */}

                      <div className="content" style={{width: '360px', marginTop: '-40px'}}>

                             <div style={{display: 'table', width: '300px'}}>
                             <SunriseSunset 
                             style={{display: 'table-cell'}}
                             sunrise={this.state.sunrise} 
                             sunset={this.state.sunset}
                           />

                           <ConvertTempButton 
                             style={{display: 'table-cell'}}
                             changeUnit={this.onUnitChange}
                             onUnitChange={this.onUnitChange}
                             unit={this.state.unit}
                           />

                             </div>      
                          <DailyHourly forecastdays={forecastdays} hourlyforecast={hourlyforecast}/>   
                       </div>
                      {/* Forecast Cards Ends*/  }          
                  </div> 
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
</div>
          {/* Video Background Ends */}
          </div>
          {/* Weather Card Ends */}

          </React.Fragment>

        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App
```

I know above code is not appropriate,but, then What is proper method for achieving the result? Any suggestions or changes in the code is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The unit of the temperature is whatever the particular weather API you are using is returning. Which weather API are you using?

Comment: Just use `this.state.unit`?

Comment: I'am using weatherbit api

Comment: Pranav did you able to resolve problem? Did you try @MaazSyedAdeeb suggestion? I the issue not resolved I will post an answer.

Comment: I'am bit confused where shall this.state.unit be used, according to @MaazSyedAdeeb? When I input particular city and then toggle celcius to farenheit the weather info is back to my current location

Comment: What answer do you have @SuleymanSah can you post it please

Comment: Can you add all of your App.js code including render?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes why not

Comment: To be able solve the problem.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I have edited th above code, Please see above

Comment: It has another components inside it, you had better to create minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Ya but that's all I have... The getWeather function is in Form component... See above in the code for reference

Answer (score 0):

I guess this weatherbit API provides you temperature in Celsius by default. So each time you call the api the result you get would be in Celsius itself. You can use a state variable to convert it to Fahrenheit or any other unit and vice versa.

for example :

```
state = {
  unit: 'C'
} 

handleToggle = () => {
 if(this.state.unit === 'C'){
   var temp = this.state.temp;
   //convert to Fahrenheit 
   var newtemp = //newvalue
   this.setState({ unit: 'F', temp: newtemp});
}else{
  var temp = this.state.temp;
  //convert to Celcius
  newtemp = //newvalue
  this.setState({ unit: 'C', temp: newtemp});
}
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I missed the way you're calling `setState`. You can do it by adding both your callbacks into another callback and then use `this.state.unit` inside both `getWeather` and `fetchWeather`. Like

```
onUnitChange = (newUnit) => {
    this.setState({
        unit: newUnit
    }, () => { this.fetchWeather(); this.getWeather(); })
}
```

A working simplified example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };

  onButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ value }) => ({ value: ++value }),
      () => {
        this.first();
        this.second();
      }
    );
  };

  first = () => {
    console.log("First:", this.state.value);
  };

  second = () => {
    console.log("Second:", this.state.value);
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Value: {value}</div>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Update</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In the above code, getWeather(e) has e.preventDefault() which throws an error when called from other function

Comment: Yup. That's because you're expecting it to be an event handler as well as a function that can be called independently. So you'll need to manage both types of invocations. In this case, figure out a way to pass whatever is coming from `e` as extra parameters when you call it independently.